# NgChatModule does not have a module def (ɵmod property) after migration to angular 16

Tags: angular, angular16

I have migrated angular from 14 to 16 (14 to 15 to 16). I am using `ng-chat` module.

It was working with angular 15, but now It is showing this on `ng serve`

```
Error: NgChatModule does not have a module def (ɵmod property)
    at transitiveScopesFor (core.mjs:24566:11)
    at core.mjs:24596:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at transitiveScopesForNgModule (core.mjs:24593:32)
    at transitiveScopesFor (core.mjs:24533:16)
    at core.mjs:24596:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at transitiveScopesForNgModule (core.mjs:24593:32)
    at transitiveScopesFor (core.mjs:24533:16)
    at setScopeOnDeclaredComponents (core.mjs:24496:30)
```

most of the modules are showing this, on angular 15, everything was good.

any help on this?

Comment: Regarding to the [ng-chat Repository](https://github.com/rpaschoal/ng-chat) the project has been archived by the owner on May 17, 2023 and is now read-only. This means that there is no maintenance anymore and Angular 16 maybe can't support it anymore.

**Alternative:**
Try to remove `ng-chat` from **nodes_modules** folder and re-install it.  In worst case you could go back to View Engine till you find another solution...

Comment: yes the module is deprecated now, tried reinstalling it no luck!!! any thing like patch or something?

Comment: No the developer stopped this project and we can't expect any updates for ng-chat anymore.